# Make reliable and fast server for Node.js chat based application

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

Good day everyone.

We have a serious problem with server, Our dedicated server is not responding with high traffic, server response goes too slow whenever 2500 daily active users. Total users are more than 80000.

We have a chat based application for both iOS and Android and API's are written in Node.js and database used MongoDB.

Please suggest me how we can improve server speed? which server should I use? is single server is enough for this kind of daily active users? Our users are increasing day by day and we need to make it more reliable.

We are thinking to move to Amazon and should use load balancer but will it be a good idea?

Server Info:

---

Commercial name
ADVANCE-LE - Intel Xeon W-2145 - 128GB DDR4 ECC 2666MHz - 2x SSD NVMe 960GB Datacenter Class Soft RAID

---

System (OS):

---

Cpanel 11.68 autoinstaller (CentOS 7 64bit)

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 1):

Very hard to guess without knowing your app architecture and more details.

You will have to identify where is the bottleneck, i.e. which part of your app is overloaded. Is it the Web server, Node app, database, storage, something else?

Once that is known you will have to optimise that part - perhaps add some caching, indexes, split it up, optimise the code paths, etc.

Building scalable apps is not trivial and using bigger hardware is usually not the answer. It only buys you some time. Optimising the architecture and the code is the answer. It’s harder but pays off much more.

Hope that helps :)